# How to get the parant object of TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, treeview

I want to set a property in my ViewModel with the value of the parent Treeview node, but can't get the right way.
Here is the code:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
    {
         this.MainViewModel.SelectedCustomer = (Customer)e.NewValue;
         this.MainViewModel.FinishConSiteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        this.MainViewModel.SelectedConstructionSite = (ConstructionSite)e.NewValue;
        // here I want to set "this.MainViewModel.SelectedCustomer" this is the parent node.
        this.MainViewModel.FinishConSiteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

And the XAML

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructionSiteDictionary.Values}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructionSites}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding DisplayableInfos}"/>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution for my own question:

```
        private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
            {
                this.MainViewModel.SelectedCustomer = (Customer)e.NewValue;
                this.MainViewModel.FinishConSiteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                this.MainViewModel.SelectedConstructionSite = (ConstructionSite)e.NewValue;
                Customer customer = null;
                foreach (Customer c in this.MainViewModel.ConstructionSiteDictionary.Values)
                {
                    foreach (ConstructionSite site in c.ConstructionSites)
                    {
                        ConstructionSite selecetedSite = (ConstructionSite)e.NewValue;
                        if (site == selecetedSite)
                            customer = c;
                    }
                }
                this.MainViewModel.SelectedCustomer = customer;
                this.MainViewModel.FinishConSiteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
```

This works fine, but the runtime complexity isn't very well, when ConstructionSiteDictionary has a lot of data. Has anyone a better solution?